Law of large number for non-integrable random variables
Let ${X_1,X_2,\dots}$ be iid copies of an unsigned random variable ${X}$ with infinite mean, and write ${S_n := X_1 + \dots + X_n}$. Show that ${S_n/n}$ diverges to infinity in probability, in the sense that ${{\bf P}( S_n/n \geq M ) \rightarrow 1}$ as ${n \rightarrow \infty}$ for any fixed ${M < \infty}$.
Attempt: Fix some $M > 0$. Since $X$ is not absolutely integrable, it must be that ${\bf P}(X = \infty) = \delta > 0$. By assumption, $\forall 0 < \theta \leq 1$, we can choose a sufficiently large $n$ such that $\theta {\bf E}X1_{|X| \leq n} \geq \theta n \delta > M$. We write ${X_i = X_{i,\leq n} + X_{i, > n}}$ where ${X_{i, \leq n} := X_i 1_{|X_i| \leq n}}$ and ${X_{i,>n} := X_i 1_{|X_i| > n}}$, and similarly decompose ${S_n = S_{n,\leq} + S_{n,>}}$ where
$\displaystyle  S_{n,\leq} := X_{1,\leq n} + \dots + X_{n,\leq n}$
and
$\displaystyle  S_{n,>} := X_{1,>n} + \dots + X_{n,>n}$. By the iid assumption and the Paley-Zygmund inequality, we get:
$\displaystyle {\bf P}(S_{n, \leq} / n > M) \geq {\bf P}(S_{n, \leq} / n > \theta {\bf E}X1_{|X| \leq n}) = [{\bf P}(X1_{|X| \leq n} > \theta {\bf E}X1_{|X| \leq n})]^n
\geq [(1 - \theta)^{2} \frac{({\bf E}X1_{|X| \leq n})^2}{{\bf E}(X1_{|X| \leq n})^2}]^n \stackrel{n}\sim (1 - \theta)^{2n}$.
As $\theta > 0$ is arbitrary, we conclude that
$\displaystyle {\bf P}(S_n/n \geq M) = {\bf P}(S_{n,\leq}/n + S_{n,>}/n \geq M) \rightarrow 1$ as desired.
Is this a valid truncation argument?

$f(x) \propto 1/x^2$

It is not true that $X$ must be infinity with positive probability. Also, what does “unsigned “ mean?

I don’t understand the purpose of $\theta$. I would assume a truncation argument would define $Y_n=min[X_n, v]$.

"Since $X$ is not absolutely integrable, it must be that ${\bf P}(X = \infty) = \delta > 0$". This is entirely false. There are many examples like the Cauchy distribution. Other than that, it is often helpful to think of functions from the probability space $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$. So take any function like $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and see that it is finite for almost every $x\in[0,1]$, i.e. $\lambda{x:f(x)=\infty}=0$ but $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x},dx=\infty$.

@Michael: Correct, the non-integrability assumption only implies non-negligible tails. And the word "unsigned" simply means that $X \in [0, \infty]$.

Assuming that $X_n\ge 0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_n)=+\infty$ (and absolutely no need to assume it's extended random variable, i.e. we will assume $\mathbb{P}(X_n<\infty)=1$), the argument is the following.
Let $M>0$ and $X_n^{(M)}=\min(X_n,M)$. Then $X_n^{(M)}$s are i.i.d. with finite mean (as they are in $[0,M]$). Also by bounded convergence theorem
$$
\mu_M=\mathbb{E}(X_n^{(M)})\to +\infty\text{ as } M\to\infty.
$$
At the same time
$$
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\ge \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{(M)}
$$
As $n\to\infty$, the RHS of the above converges to $\mu_M$, hence
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\ge \liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_ i^{(M)}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_ i^{(M)}=\mu_M\text{ a.s.}
$$
But the LHS does not depend on $M$, and the RHS $\to\infty$ as $M\to\infty$ so we get
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\ge \infty.
$$

I've just worked out the same solution. It's really obvious after realizing that one can make the horizontally truncated expectation as large as desired, plus the monotone convergence theorem.
